# Logstash jdbc connector unable to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, logstash

Logstash syncing data from MySQL database was working fine for months. But it fails now and shows the below error:

```
2020-03-26T13:40:00,063][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ]
Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times 
{:error_message=>"Java::ComMysqlJdbcExceptionsJdbc4::CommunicationsException: 
Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet successfully received from the 
server was 3 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the 
server was 2 milliseconds ago."}
```

Here is my Logstash configuration:

```
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://ec2-52-20-227-220.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/resource_map"     
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_user => "...."
    jdbc_password => "....."
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar"
    statement => "select st.id as site_history_id, st.site_id as site_id , concat('{', '\"name\":\"', coalesce(st.name, ''), '\",\"latitude\":', coalesce(st.lat, 0), ',\"longitude\":', coalesce(st.lng, 0),  ',\"collection\":', st.collection_id, ',' ,group_concat(concat('\"', cast(fd.code as char(50)), '\":' , concat('\"',  cast(json_extract_c(st.properties, concat('$.', fd.id)) as char character set utf8) ,'\"'))), ',\"createdAt\":\"',  cast(st.created_at as char(50)), '\"}') as property
    from site_histories as st join fields as fd on fd.collection_id = st.collection_id
    where st.id > :sql_last_value and st.collection_id = 32 
    group by st.id
    order by site_history_id;"
    schedule => "*/3 * * * *"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => site_history_id
    last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/logs/last_run_metadata"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What has changed since when it ran fine and now? And which Logstash version are you running?

Comment: No change is made actually....and the Logstash version is 7.6.1